# How do i add 'default text' in a php form

Tags: php, textarea, placeholder

I'd like the following code to be change so that the textarea has a default value that disappears when it's focused.

```
if ($txtActive != 'N') {
    $value = (isset($_POST['mod_SEF_textarea'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['mod_SEF_textarea']) : "";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th align='" . $labelAlign . "'></th>";
    echo "<td><textarea class='SEFTextArea' name='mod_SEF_textarea' id='textarea' value=\'tester\' rows='$txtRows' cols='$txtCols'>" . stripslashes($value) . "" . "</textarea>";
    echo ($txtError) ? "<br /><b style='color: $errorTxtColor;'>$txtError</b>" : '';
    //  echo "wendy TESTerburger";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want.

Comment: How do i add 'default text' in a php form…??

The text that displays in input fields and when u click to enter ur info it disappears...??

Comment: "I have replaced all the < & > with [ & ] because the browser tries to display the html tags." - did you ever look at the stackoverflow editor? you can mark areas as code...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question properly, you would change this line, like so:

```
$value = (isset($_POST['mod_SEF_textarea'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['mod_SEF_textarea']) : "Default Text";
```

So if mod_SEF_textarea was not set, i.e. no value, the false clause would execute, which would be your default.

Comment: This places the "default text" in the field, yet it isn't removed once selected...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `placeholder` attribute.  Note that it's part of the HTML5 spec, only works with the latest versions of some browsers.  If you want it to work in older browsers, you'll need to do it with Javascript.

```
echo "<td><textarea class='SEFTextArea' name='mod_SEF_textarea' id='textarea' value=\'tester\' rows='$txtRows' cols='$txtCols' placeholder='Default text'>" . stripslashes($value) . "" . "</textarea>";
```

Here's an example of doing it with Javascript:

```
echo "<td><textarea class='SEFTextArea' name='mod_SEF_textarea' id='textarea' value=\'tester\' rows='$txtRows' cols='$txtCols' onfocus=\"if(this.value=='Default value')this.value='';\" onblur=\"if(this.value=='')this.value='Default value';\">" . stripslashes($value) . "" . "</textarea>";
```

Very simple.

Comment: Ok i have just tested it on IE and Firefox.. and no go ! Works on chrome though, must be Html 5...

Comment: @gav: yes, it's new in HTML5.

Comment: @gav: I added the code to do it with Javascript.  Tested, works.

Comment: this is just function page, meaning only containing php, no html, no js... 

How do i use the javascript with my php code mentioned above...??

Comment: Although i didnt think this would work, I tried slotting the JS into where the PHP displays the text area...

Comment: Ooooh we are really close now.. it basically works.. but instead of having the 'default text' appear when the page loads.. instead it is blank.. But when u click in the text-input and then click out again then the 'default text' finally appears...??

Comment: Then please accept the best answer, and upvote the helpful ones.

Answer (score 1):

Any client side interaction won't use PHP - but your in client friend, JavaScript.

[I wrote a jQuery plugin that does this in a cross browser fashion](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/inputLabel).

If only targeting modern standards compliant browsers, use the `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><textarea class='SEFTextArea' name='mod_SEF_textarea' id='textarea' value='Comments...' rows='$txtRows' cols='$txtCols' onfocus=\"if(this.value=='Comments...')this.value='';\" onblur=\"if(this.value=='')this.value='Comments...';\">" . stripslashes($value) . "Comments..." . "</textarea>";
```